# How can I make a texture follow the shape of the mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I consider myself a newbie Blender user (and still use 2.79). I am having trouble applying a texture to a floor that's an 'S' type shape, so that the texture follows that shape. Following a couple previously answered questions, I am currently trying texture coordinate>mapping and a checkered texture to test, but I clearly don't know what I am doing. I marked the seams around the outside, I unwrapped, and I am still lost. Could someone give me any tips please?

This is what I am dealing with right now:

[image: problem1]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can unwrap your floor with the *Follow Active Quads* mode (in *Edit* mode, switch to *Face* mode, select all the faces, make one active, unwrap), it will square the UVs:

[image]

Give your object the material you want, use the UV output socket of the *Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

Here is what it gives (I've given a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to the object):

[image]

Comment: thank you kindly, I managed it!!! :D

Comment: @nekomancer Don't forget to mark the answer as *accepted* if it helped :)